# What is the meaning of this part of sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension

I don't understand "どこまでいってもＡＩから嫌われると" from this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0611.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_001),
here is the paragraph:

> ＡＩと人権に詳しい、慶応義塾大学の山本龍彦教授は「ＡＩによるプロファイリングは、採用や人事にとどまらず、金融や保険、教育にも広がると考えられている。非常に多くのデータを使い、判断のプロセスはブラックボックス化されるため、自分がなぜ落とされたのかが分からない。**どこまでいってもＡＩから嫌われると**、再挑戦したり、人生をやり直して、這い上がっていくことが非常に難しくなり『バーチャルスラム』とも言える新たな被差別集団が生まれかねない」と指摘する。

Especially どこまでいっても(I find things like [どこまでいっても面白い](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%93%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E9%9D%A2%E7%99%BD%E3%81%84) but I'm not sure how it works without the 面白い at the end because I don't really understand the logic behind "どこまでいっても" ) but even the remainder (ＡＩから嫌われると) I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どこまでいっても means literally "no matter where you go", this is used like どこまでいっても、ここは田んぼだけの田舎だよ(Here is the country that has constant scenery of rice fields, no matter where you go).

However it can mean "whatever" and "no matter how", so どこまでいってもＡＩから嫌われると means "If they are disliked by the AI, whatever they do.".

どこまでいってもおもしろい means "very interesting", "not lacking in interest".

Can you grasp the nuance of どこまでいっても?

Comment: Yes, I thought that "no matter where you go" in this case meant "in any workplace they try to get a job, they are hated"(several people told me that ) but actually in this case it means "they are disliked by the AI, whatever they do", thank you Yuuichi Tam.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a native speaker, so here is my humble answer:

The interviewee is talking about how AI systems could be used to profile people for things like employment and insurance. Since the AI can use a lot of data, and the process by which it decides is hard to understand ("a black box"), one can find themselves in the situation where they don't even know why they are being declined. In fact, **no matter where they go, they are disliked by the AI**, which can be very hard to fix.

(Please refer to the comment replies for more discussion on the nuance of the original text.)

Comment: If you downvote please feel free to explain why

Comment: ダウンボートしたの私じゃないですけど、この「どこまで行っても嫌われると～」は、「どこに行っても(no matter where they go)」って意味じゃなくて、「何回やっても・いくら頑張っても・いつまで続けても、しつこく・いつまでも・ずっと嫌われ続けると～」みたいな意味です。その「と」は if って意味の接続助詞で、「嫌われたら～」って意味です

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the nuance. If you'll allow me to simplify your remarks, I think the addition of まで emphasizes the extent of the effort of the victim.

Comment: Translating parts of @Chocolate's comment in case it helps anybody: Some alternate ways to define どこまでいっても: "No matter how many times you do it", "No matter how hard you try", "persistently no matter how long you continue", etc, you're still disliked by the AI.